# data-i18n doesn't display symbols

Tags: jquery, i18next

I created a button. The language on it has to be changed whenever required. I wrote the following code to do the task

```
var $button = $( '<a class="btn">' )
 .attr( 'href', '#' ).prepend(
 '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>', ' ' )
 .attr( 'data-i18n', 'text' )
 .tooltip( {
    title: 'change item'
   } );
```

this successfully change the language but it doesn't display icon "+".

```
var $button = $( '<a class="btn">' )
   .text( 'sample text' )
   .append( '<span data-i18n="text">sample text</span>' )
   .attr( 'href', '#' ).prepend(
   '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>', ' ' )
    .tooltip( {
        title: 'change item'
    } );
```

The second case worked and displayed it correctly including the change in language. But I can't understand the mistake in the first code sample. can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you use jquery-i18next:

`<a ... data-i18n="text"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>hello</a>` will get it's content replaced by the translation given by key text. So after translation you will have: whatever the translation is`

having it like you did in the second sample asserts only the inner span gets replaced not the complete content of the anchor tag.

but you also can do something like `<a ... data-i18n="[prepend]text">...`: https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#prepend-content to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code syntax is invalid. You have an extra `'` after the text variable inside the second attr function

Your code:

```
var $button = $( '<a class="btn">' )
 .attr( 'href', '#' ).prepend(
 '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>', ' ' )
 .attr( 'data-i18n', text' )
 .tooltip( {
    title: 'change item'
 });
```

Valid code:

```
var $button = $( '<a class="btn">' )
 .attr( 'href', '#' ).prepend(
 '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>', ' ' )
 .attr( 'data-i18n', text )
 .tooltip( {
    title: 'change item'
 });
```

Comment: thanks, @Alex Gray for the reply, and sorry to say that it is actually a typo mistake I made here. I shall update the question.